# Add an additional condition into an exisiting IIF statement - SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to add an additional condition into an existing IIF statement in SSRS:

```
=Sum(
       IIF(
              Fields!Group.Value = "CRT" OR
              Fields!Group.Value = "Escalations" OR
              Fields!Group.Value = "RID" OR
              Fields!Group.Value = "Dissatisfactions"
              ,Fields!ComplaintID.Value
              ,IIF(
                           Fields!Group.Value = "Calls"
                           ,Fields!Calls.Value
                           ,0
                     )
       )
)
```

What I'm trying to add is an additional IIF statement (as per the below snipper), to ensure that where my group's name is 'All Dissatisfactions', I want 'Total Dissatisfactions' column to be summed up. I've been trying to add this additional condition with no luck.

```
IIF(
     Fields!Group.Value = " All Dissatisfactions"
     ,Fields! TotalDissatisfactions.Value
     ,0
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
=Sum(
       IIF(Fields!Group.Value = " All Dissatisfactions",
       Fields! TotalDissatisfactions.Value,
       IIF(
              Fields!Group.Value = "CRT" OR
              Fields!Group.Value = "Escalations" OR
              Fields!Group.Value = "RID" OR
              Fields!Group.Value = "Dissatisfactions"
              ,Fields!ComplaintID.Value
              ,IIF(
                           Fields!Group.Value = "Calls"
                           ,Fields!Calls.Value
                           ,0
                     )
       )
       )           
)
```